# Creating a workload on a sample database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have to create a sample database and create a transactional workload of 10-15 gigs. 
Any idea how I can generate this load? It might be on an empty database with a single table or on AdventureWorks database. All I need is transactions keep inserting or modifying the data for an extended period of time.

Thank you all in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could create a table and load it using a while loop. I believe Master.dbo.spt_values (could have the table name wrong) has a list of numbers, but the easiest way would be like this:

```
Declare @MyRow as bigint = 0
Create table dbo.StupidBigTable ( obj_id bigint identity(1,1),
        StupidBigField nchar(1024) )

While @MyRow <= 999999999 --I don't remember how big bigint can get
Begin
    Insert into dbo.StupidBigTable (StupidBigField)
    Cast(@MyRow as nchar)
    Set @MyRow = @MyRow + 1
End
```

I haven't done the math on this really, but char(1024) should take up 1024 bytes so nchar(1024) should consume 2048 bytes. That'll be at least 2KB per row then multiply that by 999999999 or whatever.

Oh, and you can't create a DB > 10GB using SQL Express. Don't know your setup, but worth mentioning.